A unique_ptr defined as base class then cast in as derived class
I would like to see two object printing from two different derived classes, and the key is to cast the object to derived class after being define as base. Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include "memory"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
    ~Base() {};
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived1: public Base<int>
{
public:
    Derived1() {}
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base<int>
{
public:
    Derived2() {}
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Derived2"<< std::endl;
    }
};

class user
{
public:
    user();
    user(int type)
    :m_type(type)
    {
        switch(type) // change should be done here?
        {
        case 1:
            m_ptr = make_unique<Derived1>(); // m_ptr still base? why not derived
            break;
        case 2:
            m_ptr = make_unique<Derived2>();;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    ~user() {};
    void UserPrint()
    {
        m_ptr->Print();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base<int>> m_ptr;
    int m_type;
};

int main()
{
    user a(1);
    user b(2);

    a.UserPrint();
    b.UserPrint();

    return 0;
}

I am expecting to see
Print from Derived1
Print from Derived2

but instead, I am seeing
Print from Base
Print from Base

How to change the code to make it work? I would prefer to change in the constructor of the user(int type).

Unless there is something you are not telling us, your life will be a lot easier if you make the Print method virtual.

@user4581301 I totally agree with you :D

Simplification tip: class Base { public: void Print() { std::cout << "Print from Base\n"; } }; -- There is no need to have a template, and there is no need to define a do-nothing constructor/destructor. To make it even simpler, change class to struct and drop public:. While these details could have value in real code, they are distracting noise in this example.

@JaMiTThank you for your suggestions!

I think you have some misunderstanding about overriding methods in C++ because you are missing the virtual keywords on (supossed) virtual methods:
#include <iostream>
#include "memory"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
    ~Base() {};
    virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived1: public Base<int>
{
public:
    Derived1() {}
    void Print() override
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base<int>
{
public:
    Derived2() {}
    void Print() override
    {
        std::cout << "Print from Derived2"<< std::endl;
    }
};

class user
{
public:
    user();
    user(int type)
    :m_type(type)
    {
        switch(type) // change should be done here?
        {
        case 1:
            m_ptr = make_unique<Derived1>(); // m_ptr still base? why not derived
            break;
        case 2:
            m_ptr = make_unique<Derived2>();;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    ~user() {};
    void UserPrint()
    {
        m_ptr->Print();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base<int>> m_ptr;
    int m_type;
};

int main()
{
    user a(1);
    user b(2);

    a.UserPrint();
    b.UserPrint();

    return 0;
}


Note the use of the override keyword on the derived Prints. virtual is mandatory in the base class for the overriding to work, but override emits errors if the method is supposed to override, but for one reason or another, doesn't. For example a simple typo:  print does not override Print. Oops. But if print is tagged override, the compiler catches the mistake.
